do we use "judgmental" for things that are not people?
The verb "judge" means "[intransitive, transitive] to form an opinion about somebody/something, based on the information you have" (the first meaning).
So, we use "judge" for both people and things.
For example,  You shouldn't judge her too harshly. and He judged the painting harshly.
The verb "judge" also means "judge (somebody): to give your opinion about somebody, especially when you think they are bad" (the second meaning). With this meaning, we can only put people after the verb "judge".
For example, "What gives you the right to judge other people?"
We can not say "What gives you the right to judge the painting?" because "the painting" is not people.
The adjective of the verb "judge" is "judgmental" meaning "(disapproving) judging people and criticizing them too quickly"
For example, He's judgmental about everyone except himself.
I think the adjective "judgmental" is for the second meaning of the verb "judge", not for the first meaning.
If that were true, then "he is judgmental about the painting" would be wrong.
do we use "judgmental" for things that are not people?
If not, do we have a way to say for things? For example, "He is very negative about the painting"

Please don't take the wording of one single dictionary as restrictive. If it seems to suggest something that seems improbably, check more dictionaries. MW just says "characterized by a tendency to judge harshly," without restriction. Cambridge has an entry mentioning "people," but another mentioning "disapproving of someone or something," and examples including inanimate things. Similar Dictionary.com. I found all this in surely less time than it took to type this question; wouldn't that have been easier for you?

The link for "judge" gives lots of examples of transitive judge with a non-human object: "She was asked to judge the essay competition." "Their garden was judged the best in Wales by a TV viewers' poll." "don’t judge a book by its cover". So why do you say it must refer to a person? I think you've maybe not read the whole page.

@StuartF, I am talking about "judgmental". Can I say "to be judgmental about things"?

Can the BrE spelling judgement get a look-in? For all except legal contexts.

You're onto something, but no, judgmental is not just about people.
Searching for judgmental about in the iWeb corpus, the first few hits I get are:

things that are actually scary and not just those you feel judgmental about
who is as sharp-tongued as she is judgmental about fashion, flowers and childrearing
such as being non judgmental about inner experiences

In fact, it isn't until I reach the sixteenth hit that the object is human: "You are being judgmental about the others around you"
However, where you're right is that "judgmental" often applies a judgment of the moral or ethical rightness of something, and that is typically a person, though it can also be something produced by people, such as a story, or project.
But the examples I gave show that it is not  necessarily even that - one may have a moral stance on childrearing, but criticisms of fashion and flowers probably don't have that character.
